# The button for deleting a record from the database does not work. rest ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

So, when you click on the "delete" button, the data from the table is not deleted, that is, nothing happens.
There are no errors in the console. It looks like the delete function is basically not being handled here.

[console screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NheD.png)

How can this be fixed?

---

My files:

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Cars Selling</title>

<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="listCarsSelling.js"></script>
<script src="delete.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Cars Selling List</h2>
    <p><a href="/insert">Insert new position</a></p>

    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <th>code</th>
            <th>manufacturer</th>
            <th>model</th>
            <th>color</th>
            <th>transmission</th>
            <th>body_type</th>
            <th>price</th>
            <th>action</th>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

**listCarsSelling.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.getJSON('/ListCarsSelling', function(json) {
                var tr=[];
                for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                    tr.push('<tr>');
                    tr.push('<td>' + json[i].code + '</td>');
                    tr.push('<td>' + json[i].manufacturer + '</td>');
                    tr.push('<td>' + json[i].model + '</td>');
                    tr.push('<td>' + json[i].color + '</td>');
                    tr.push('<td>' + json[i].transmission + '</td>');
                    tr.push('<td>' + json[i].body_type + '</td>');
                    tr.push('<td>' + json[i].price + '</td>');
                    tr.push('<td><button id="updatePosition">Update</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;'
                    + '<button id="deletePosition">Delete</button></td>');
                    tr.push('</tr>');
                }
                $('table').append($(tr.join('')));
            });
});
```

**delete.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#deletePosition').click(function() {
            var code = $(this).attr('code');

            $.ajax({
                url: '/ListCarsSelling/'+code,
                method: 'DELETE',
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function () {
                    window.location = '/'
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
        });
});
```

**Rest Controller**

```java
package lab3.Controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import lab3.DAO.CarSellingDAO;
import lab3.Model.CarSelling;

@RestController
public class CarSellingController {
    
    @Autowired
    private CarSellingDAO csDAO;
    
    @DeleteMapping("/ListCarsSelling/{code}")
    public String delete(@PathVariable Integer code) {
        return csDAO.deletePosition(code) + " position delete from the database";
    }
/*...other*/
}
```

---

After my update, everything now works more or less. But, there is a problem with reloading the page after deleting.
Here's what I changed:

```js
        $(document).on( "click" ,"#deletePosition", function() {
            var code = $(this).attr('value');
            console.log(code);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/ListCarsSelling/'+code,
                type: 'DELETE',
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function () {
                    window.location = '/'
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
});
```

and this part in another .js file:

```js
+ '<button id="deletePosition" value='+json[i].code+'>Delete</button></td>');
```

After pressing the button, a window pops up. I click ok and I have to refresh the page manually to update the database itself.
How to make it all happen automatically?

[page after clicking the delete button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q3xU.png)

Comment: The question doesn't appear to be related to java, please remove the java tag.

Comment: @Andrew S
I have a java application written. Mmm, I can add "rest controllers" and then everything will be ok:)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The screen shot does not indicate an issue. I can see that there is a 200 OK response. Also you may want to use POST to pass details to the Server, not DELETE.

Comment: @Twisty
This is how I show on that screen that after pressing the button, nothing happens. I need exactly the "delete" method.

Comment: @1i10 are you trying to say that no call made to the back end?

Comment: @BathriNathan
well, no errors are displayed after clicking the button. The deletion simply does not occur and I do not understand why.

Comment: @1i10 did you get any new calls in the network log when you click on the button. does the onClick event works? did you check with any console.log inside the function?

Comment: @BathriNathan
there were no new calls in the network log. It looks like the onClick event doesn't work at all, just checked it out.

Comment: then try to attach the event properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the last update, I was able to deal with the problem. It consisted of only one line.
Final solution / changes in two files:

```js
        $(document).on( "click" ,"#deletePosition", function() {
            var code = $(this).attr('value');
            var rowToDelete = $(this).closest('tr');
            console.log(code);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/ListCarsSelling/'+code,
                type: 'DELETE',
                contentType: "application/json",
                //dataType : 'json', //<---success was not processed because of this
                success: function () {
                    rowToDelete.remove(); //<--- it's better than reloading the page. Just remove line from html
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.getJSON('/ListCarsSelling', function(json) {
                var tr=[];
                for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                    tr.push('<tr>');
                    tr.push('<td>' + json[i].code + '</td>');
                    tr.push('<td>' + json[i].manufacturer + '</td>');
                    tr.push('<td>' + json[i].model + '</td>');
                    tr.push('<td>' + json[i].color + '</td>');
                    tr.push('<td>' + json[i].transmission + '</td>');
                    tr.push('<td>' + json[i].body_type + '</td>');
                    tr.push('<td>' + json[i].price + '</td>');
                    tr.push('<td><button id="updatePosition">Update</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;' // <--- the refresh button has yet to be updated, but that's a completely different story
                    + '<button id="deletePosition" value='+json[i].code+'>Delete</button></td>');
                    tr.push('</tr>');
                }
                $('table').append($(tr.join('')));
            });
            
});
```

now everything works. Hooray!:)